# How can I upload files to the replicate API with Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, artificial-intelligence, replicate

I'm trying to use the sadTalker AI model through [replicate](https://replicate.com/cjwbw/sadtalker).

The point of sadtalker is that you upload an image of a person and an audio file of someone talking, and it gives you back a deepfake video of someone talking.

I've setup a basic environment to do this. All I have is a .env file storing my API key, two files called deepfakeAudio.mp3 and deepfakeImage.jpg.

My code is as follows:

```
import Replicate from "replicate";

import dotenv from "dotenv";
import fs from "fs";

dotenv.config();

fs.readFile("./deepfakeImage.jpg", (error, inputImage) => {
  fs.readFile("./deepfakeAudio.mp3", (error, inputAudio) => {
    getVideo();
  });
});

async function getVideo(inputImage, inputAudio) {
  const replicate = new Replicate({
    auth: process.env.REPLICATE_API_TOKEN,
  });
  const output = await replicate.run(
    "cjwbw/sadtalker:3aa3dac9353cc4d6bd62a8f95957bd844003b401ca4e4a9b33baa574c549d376",
    {
      input: {
        source_image: inputImage,
        driven_audio: inputAudio
      }
    }
  );
  console.log(output);
}
```

When I try to run this, I get the error:

```
throw new Error(`API request failed: ${response.statusText}`);
            ^

Error: API request failed: Unprocessable Entity
```

The problem is that I don't know how I'm supposed to load the image and audio into the API.

To load the image and audio, I've tried 2 things:

The first time, I tried to just input the path of the audio and image. This gave me an error.

The second time, as shown in the code, I tried to load the audio and image using fs, I still get an error.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

This is very confusing because I have no idea of what I'm actually supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

The [replicate docs](https://github.com/replicate/replicate-javascript) mention that replicate expects file input as base64 encoded data URI.

So your modified code would look something like this :

```
import Replicate from "replicate";

import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

dotenv.config();

const data = await fs.readFile("./deepfakeImage.jpg", "utf-8");
const base64 = data.toString("base64");
const mimeType = "image/jpg";
const dataURI = `data:${mimeType};base64,${base64}`;


async function getVideo(inputImage, inputAudio) {
  const replicate = new Replicate({
    auth: process.env.REPLICATE_API_TOKEN,
  });
  const output = await replicate.run(
    "cjwbw/sadtalker:3aa3dac9353cc4d6bd62a8f95957bd844003b401ca4e4a9b33baa574c549d376",
    {
      input: {
        source_image: dataURI,
        driven_audio: inputAudio
      }
    }
  );
  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: The docs don't specify 'utf-8' -- I needed to remove that for it to run in the readFile call